# Looking for solution to get a count of based on the Key in Java

Tags: java, collections, iteration

I'm having LinkedHashMap which stores key and value in below format:

```
    LinkedHashMap element = new LinkedHashMap();
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ ForgetPasswordPage ~ testForgetPasswordPage_Functionality ~ testNavigateURL", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ ForgetPasswordPage ~ testForgetPasswordPage_Functionality ~ testPageLoadedWithWebComponents", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ ForgetPasswordPage ~ testForgetPasswordPage_General ~ testErrormessageOnEmailAddress", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ ForgetPasswordPage ~ testForgetPasswordPage_General ~ testErrMsgonIncorrectEmailAddress", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ ForgetPasswordPage ~ testForgetPasswordPage_LinksValidation ~ testErrormessageOnCaptcha", "Fail");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ LoginPage ~ testLoginPage_LinksValidation ~ testErrormessageOnEmailAddress", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ LoginPage ~ testLoginPage_LinksValidation ~ testErrormessageOnPassword", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ LoginPage ~ testLoginPage_General ~ testInvalidLogin", "Pass");
    element.put("Login & Related Pages ~ LoginPage ~ testLoginPage_Functionality ~ testRememberMeCheckBox", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_General ~ testErrormessageOnEmailAddress", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_General ~ testErrormessageOnPassword", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_General ~ testInvalidLogin", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_General ~ testRememberMeCheckBox", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_General ~ testNavigateURL", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_LinksValidation ~ testPageLoadedWithWebComponents", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_LinksValidation ~ testErrMsgonIncorrectEmailAddress", "Pass");
    element.put("Lead & Related Pages ~ LeadPage ~ testLeadPage_LinksValidation ~ testErrormessageOnCaptcha", "Pass");
```

```
    The Key :
    ORIGINAL: Login & Related Pages ~ ForgetPasswordPage ~         testForgetPasswordPage_Functionality ~ testNavigateURL
    CONVENTIONS: ModuleName         ~ PageName           ~         UseCaseName                          ~ TestCaseName

    Moto of doing Key in this format is to get 
    1. Module Name with Page count
    2. Module Name with Use Case count
    3. Module Name with Test Case count

    1. Page Name with Use Case count
    2. Page Name with Test Case Name count

    1. Use Case Name with Test Case Name count
```

Please help to get the count of each module. 
Expected a method wherein I will pass a module name and I will get PageCount, UseCaseCount & TestCaseCount.

For Example:

```
    Login & Related Pages = 2 (Page Count: ForgetPasswordPage, LoginPage)
    Login & Related Pages = 6 (UseCase Count: testForgetPasswordPage_Functionality, testForgetPasswordPage_General, testForgetPasswordPage_LinksValidation, testLoginPage_LinksValidation, testLoginPage_General, testLoginPage_Functionality)
    Login & Related Pages = 9 (TestCase Count: testNavigateURL, testPageLoadedWithWebComponents, testErrormessageOnEmailAddress, testErrMsgonIncorrectEmailAddress, testErrormessageOnCaptcha, testErrormessageOnEmailAddress, testErrormessageOnPassword, testInvalidLogin, testRememberMeCheckBox)
```

Please help me to get the resolution.

Comment: Why don't you replace yours String key with Class Key, which contains fields `moduleName`, `pageName`, `useCaseName` and `testCaseName`?

Comment: I'm new to collections, suddenly came up with this scenarios. Can you please elaborate more on this.

Comment: What is the purpose of Value in Map? I think you need only List, not a Map if you'll iterate all of them every time

Comment: I'm getting HashMap as input. Now i need to design a Email Template for reporting and status update.

Comment: I cannot change the HashMap input, i need to play with that only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static LinkedHashMap complete = new LinkedHashMap();
    static Set Pagecounter = new TreeSet();
    static Set Usecounter = new TreeSet();
    static Set Testcounter = new TreeSet();
    static String totalNumber;

   /**
     * @param logData
     * @return
     */
    public static LinkedHashMap logIteration(LinkedHashMap logData) {
        Set keys = logData.keySet();
        Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
        boolean available = false;
        boolean tcAvailable = false;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            String value = (String) logData.get(key);
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Fail")) {
                tcAvailable = true;
            }
            String[] listArray = key.split("~");
            if (complete.size() > 0) {
                Set moduleName = complete.keySet();
                Iterator itr1 = moduleName.iterator();
                while (itr1.hasNext()) {
                    String key1 = (String) itr1.next();
                    if (listArray[0].equals(key1)) {
                        available = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        available = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                available = true;
            }
            if (available) {
                processControl(listArray, tcAvailable);
            } else {
                clearSet();
                if (tcAvailable) {
                    tcAvailable = false;
                }
                processControl(listArray, tcAvailable);
                available = false;
            }
        }
        return complete;
    }

    /**
     * @param listArray
     * @param tcstatus
     */
    private static void processControl(String[] listArray, boolean tcstatus){
        Pagecounter.add(listArray[1].trim());
        Usecounter.add(listArray[2].trim());
        Testcounter.add(listArray[3].trim());
        if (tcstatus) {
            totalNumber = Pagecounter.size() + "~" + Usecounter.size() + "~" + Testcounter.size() + "~Fail";
        } else {
            totalNumber = Pagecounter.size() + "~" + Usecounter.size() + "~" + Testcounter.size() + "~Pass";
        }
        complete.put(listArray[0], totalNumber);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static void clearSet(){
        Pagecounter.clear();
        Usecounter.clear();
        Testcounter.clear();
    }
```

The Answer looks like as below

Login & Related Pages=2~6~8~Fail

Lead & Related Pages=1~1~5~Pass